# Sonar jacoco hybris

Tags: ant, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to generate jacoco report and publish it in sonar for the junit test cases in hybris project. When I publish the jacoco report in sonar, the code coverage includes OOB classes also.

I have excluded the unwanted extensions using sonar.excludedExtensions=xx,yy
I need to exclude some directories inside my custom extensions.

I tried using sonar.jacoco.excludes=x.y.z.* and sonar.exclusions=xx/** but nothing works.

How can I exclude classes or directories during jacoco analysis. I have OOB acc-ant-sonar.xml file as below in hybris which drives the jacoco analysis.

```
<project name="acc.ant.sonar" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="path/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="xx.jar"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="jacocoalltests" description="runs allstests with jacoco attached">

        <jacoco:agent property="agentvmparam"
                      append="true"
                      output="file"
                      destfile="output_path/jacoco.exec"
                />

        <property name="testclasses.extensions" value="${extname}"/>
        <ant dir="${platformhome}" target="alltests" inheritrefs="false">
            <property name="standalone.javaoptions" value="${agentvmparam} ${standalone.javaoptions}"/>
        </ant>
    </target>
  </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have multiple possibilities, which you can use together, or alone

1. telling sonar to ignore oob-classes by setting `sonar.coverage.exclusions`- as described here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters
2. configuring jacoco to only track your classes with `ìncludes`
   https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html - but i highly recommend to look at the documentation, we just use that for the javaagent directly, and i am not 100% sure if this is 100% working the same way.

   ```
   includes=your.package.*
   ```
3. might be useful take a look at the Hybris test target -> you can configure packages with `testclasses.packages`, to reduce the tests which are running. This also might kill your oob coverage, as those test for oob code will not be executed

Comment: I have tried your suggestions sonar.coverage.exclusions and testclasses.packages while running my comamnds, I got some improvements. But now the issue is I am executing two commands **ant jacocoalltests and jacocoallwebtests**. the log/junit dir replaces the files generated by first command when I run second command. Is there any way to specify different log dir path for both the commands.

Comment: Yes, use the jacoco destfile property

Comment: When I use destfile property, exec files get generated in different dir but files like TESTS-TestSuites.xml, index.html goes under log/junit as default.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon, that helped!!